# SignalR cannot be used with .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-core

I am trying to install **SignalR** using NuGet package manager in my **C# Asp.Net core** project, but I get this error that SignalR is not compatible with .net core, is it really not supporter yet? or can I do something to get it work? (I am using VS2017 if it was important to mention that). The error:

```
Restoring packages for D:\Test\Test.WebAPI\Test.WebAPI.csproj...
Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
Package Microsoft.Owin 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Owin 2.1.0 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Test.WebAPI'.
```

## UPDATE:

SignalR for ASP.Net **Core** is at the moment (01.01.2018) available in NuGet as alpha version.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/

## UDPATE 01.06.2018:

SignalR is now available for ASP.Net Core 2.1

Comment: SignalR is not yet part of ASP.Net Core, but it's on the roadmap.

Comment: You can try the beta I guess.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Web Sockets are already in .NET Core I believe. But not SignalR. So if you want web sockets, you'll need to roll your own implementation. Or just use .NET Framework for now.

Comment: @DavidG That would be brilliant, do you know how to do that?

Comment: You know the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/signalr) is available right? You could theoretically download it and see what state it's in and even begin using it. I wouldn't trust it for production purposes of course.

Comment: @mason this link is exactly what made me confused, (I believed that it is there somehow). OK I will try it, it would be nice with NuGet package somewhen to make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Latest as of Microsoft Build 2017 (around May 12, 2017): SignalR for .NET Core is still under development targeting preview around Q3 2017 and release around Q4 2017. Github site is https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR and Build presentation is at https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8078 from which you can also see the slide deck

Comment: @Seafish Thank you for the infos! I will take a look on the video today, I am still very excited about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SignalR 2 is built for .NET Framework, not for .NET Core. They are still working on SignalR for .NET Core.

An [old revision](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap/2537ab34911e2854e2305909d480e409e14cf27b) of the ASP.NET Core Roadmap shows SignalR as part of ASP.NET Core 1.2. The [latest revision](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap/b49bda1f8f40975b39d14d199a9ddac0a2beb45e) makes no reference to SignalR (or any of the framework) but does mention 1.2 is scheduled for Q2 2017.

There's [a video](https://vimeo.com/204078084) where the Microsoft guys are discussing SignalR in ASP.NET Core. It's an hour long so I'm not going to watch it for you. But perhaps some useful information is in there.

Comment: Do you have any updates about SignalR for ASP.Net Core? I googled a little bit with no obvious results.

Comment: Did you look at their GitHub page? https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/README.md

Comment: Yes, but I was not sure if it was officially released or it is just still in development stage.

Comment: It's open source software. It's always in development. If you're curious about if there's been a stable release, I have no idea. If I were to try and find out, I could Google around just like you. Or I could open an issue on their GitHub repo and ask what the plans are.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant, if there are any stable release. I will keep searching, and I will try it out later today. Thank you.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin now there is an Alpha 2 release. which i use now. and it works fine

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently working on a .net core / angular 4 project using signalr.

There are a handful of seed examples on google, but one thing which may trip most people up trying to download signalr via nuget is the fact that it's a different package repo - you need to update Nuget.config in your solution to reference the more bleeding edge repo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetCore" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What name for .net  core?

Comment: Looks like 1.0.0 (preview 3) only works with netstandard 2.0: `Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-preview3-25758.
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-preview3-25758 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-preview3-25758 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)`

Comment: @mikebridge did you end up finding an appropriate version that supports 1.1?

Comment: @FiringSquadWitness I dropped SignalR altogether and am now using websockets (via Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets) and Pusher.  This works really smoothly with my React front end.

Answer (score 4):

**[SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) for asp.net core**

*EDIT:* [SignalR for asp.net core has been released with .net standard 2.1.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

[This package targets .net standard 2.0 and is still in the alpha state.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/)

[It doesn't seem like a stable release is out before .net standard 2.1.](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/429#issuecomment-323500447)

[image]

The packages can be found on [myget](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-ci-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR).

If you load balance your signalr hub you can use redis as backpane.

---

**SignalR for asp.net**

And there is also the SignalR package for the .net framework which allready has a stable release. It can be found on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/).

For [load balancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr) the following backpane types are supported:

- Azure Service Bus
- Redis
- SQL Server

---

**[SignalR.Server](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) for asp.net core**
 (update 18.09.2017: not available anymore)

***Do not use this package!***

This is the deprecated package which targets .net 4.5.1 and .net standard 1.6. No stable package has and will ever be released.

The preview packages can be found on [myget](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server).

If you load balance your signalr hub you can use sql server as backpane. (But the [implementation is broken](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-SqlServer/issues/15))

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.  SignalR is built on OWIN, which is compatible with asp.net core if you target the full framework, but not dotnet core.

Comment: any idea how to do this? i cannot seem to find any example of this setup

Answer (score 1):

I recently migrated an MVC5 application that used SignalR to **ASP.NET Core 1.1** (`netcoreapp1.1`). I found an unofficial package (`Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server`) that worked straight almost without any changes to my existing code.

#### csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server" Version="0.2.0-alpha1" />
```

#### Startup - ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

#### Startup - Configure method

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseSignalR();
```

Comment: Sounds practical, I will give it a try later. do you have any idea about the official SignalR core? is it stable? What do you mean with `netcoreapp1.1) which used SignalR`? is it the official open source SignalR or the old one?

Comment: The MVC5 app I migrated used the official SignalR and I failed to realize SignalR was incompatible with .NET Core until I started the migration. Luckily that nuget package rescued me! It's not official (you can tell by the package name) but it worked.

Comment: Ok correct, the nornal old SingalR is not compatible with .Net core 1.1, We are still waiting for a stable version of SignalR core. Till that time, I will give that package you mentioned a try, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following packages can be found on NuGet.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR             1.0.0-alpha1-final
Components for providing real-time bi-directional communication across the Web.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Redis       1.0.0-alpha1-final 
Redis for ASP.NET Core SignalR.

The packages supported .NETSTandard,Version=v2.0 Now.
I used the packages in my projects.
Angular 4 + SignalR

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is introduced with .NET Core 
Here is the link for implementation 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TrttIkbs6c](http://.Net%20core%20with%20SignalR)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)