# Connect to Azure SignalR service from a .NET Core console app?

Tags: azure, signalr

I will start this off by saying that I am new to SignalR. I know the basic concepts, but have never personally written an app using SignalR until now.

With a little effort I have the basic Azure SignalR ChatRoom example running locally connected to an Azure SignalR instance (will only run using 'dotnet run' from the command line; if started from within Visual Studio it stops as soon as I try to change the name in the JS prompt window).

What I would like to do now is send messages (no need to receive) from a .NET Core console application and have them show up in the chatroom instance the browser is connected to. This is to simulate a background process doing some work and then sending a message to an Azure SignalR hub informing all clients of the outcome.

I created a new .NET Core app and when I try to add the `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR` package, I get an error message stating "**error: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.SignalR' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:...\TestingAzureSignalR\ChatRoom.Console\ChatRoom.Console.csproj'.**"

Are there any examples of this anywhere that can help me out? Something as simple as working with the ChatRoom Quickstart example?

Comment: Did you find another way to directly connect to Azure SignalR from a console app or did you go the REST route?

Answer (score 0):

If the version of .NET Core you used is under 2.1, please update it to 2.1 because SignalR was released on .NET Core 2.1.

More information about SignalR on .NET Core we can refer to: [Get started with SignalR on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

We can download .NET Core 2.1 SDK at: [All Downloads of .NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all)

Similar thread for your reference:

[SignalR cannot be used with .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730468/signalr-cannot-be-used-with-net-core)

Comment: I have .NET Core 2.1 installed (`dotnet --version` returns 2.1.201 and `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>` in my .csproj file). I already have an ASP.NET Core web app running and communicating with Azure SignalR. What I am looking for guidance on is how to write a .NET Core Console application (possibly an Azure Function later on) that pushes data to an Azure SignalR hub so that the connected web clients get notified of the new message (eventually JSON data).

Answer (score 0):

On server you need to get a hub context using dependency injection and call `SendAsync` method to send to clients. For example:

```
public class Sender
{
    public Sender(IHubContext<MyHub> context)
    {
        context.Clients.All.SendAsync(...);
    }
}
```

One sample can be found here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/FlightMap, which uses a timer to broadcast data to clients.

For the "incompatible framework" error you met, you need to specify the version number when you add Microsoft.Azure.SignalR to your project as this package is still a prerelease:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.SignalR --version 1.0.0-preview1-10011
```

Comment: Does this library work with .NET Core Console applications (not ASP.NET Core applications)? I want to be able to have some external process (like a Console application or an Azure Function) send data to an Azure SignalR hub and have that message be sent to all connected web clients. Is this possible currently?

Comment: This has to be a ASP.NET Core application. If you really don't want to use ASP.NET Core (for example in Azure functions), you can use the REST APIs provided by the service to send message to hub. Examples can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/RealtimeSignIn

https://medium.com/@philippbauknecht/serverless-real-time-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-azure-signalr-service-c70e781ff3c3

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was able to perform a basic call through the REST API without issue but am getting a Bad Request response when trying to send a message to a group. The REST API definition (https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/swagger.json) says this should be as simple as adding "/group/{groupName}" to the URL.